# javascript compare array with object list and insert the new array value

Tags: javascript, lodash

how to compare array and array of object and insert the new one, in new array

```
const dayList = [
    {'key':'Mon','value':1}, 
    {'key':'Tue','value':5},
    {'key':'Wed','value':10},
    {'key':'Fri','value':18},
    {'key':'Sat','value':80},
    {'key':'Sun','value':20},
]
const dayArray = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
```

I need to compare `dayList` with `dayArray` and insert new one like this

```
const result = [
        {'key':'Mon','value':1}, 
        {'key':'Tue','value':5},
        {'key':'Wed','value':10},
        {'key':'Thu','value':0},
        {'key':'Fri','value':18},
        {'key':'Sat','value':80},
        {'key':'Sun','value':20},
    ]
```

if this can be done using lodash?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of day by key out of the `dayList`. Iterate the `dayArray` using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and if the day is not in the `dayMap` return an empty object:

```js
const dayList = [
    {'key':'Mon','value':1}, 
    {'key':'Tue','value':5},
    {'key':'Wed','value':10},
    {'key':'Fri','value':18},
    {'key':'Sat','value':80},
    {'key':'Sun','value':20},
]

const dayArray = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

const dayMap = new Map(dayList.map((o) => [o.key, o]))

const result = dayArray.map((key) => dayMap.has(key) ? dayMap.get(key) : { key, value: 0 })

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all the keys in the array of JSON object. Then find the difference and push the difference object to the array.

```
var dayArray = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
var diff = _.difference(dayArray,_.map(dayList,'key'));
if(diff.length>0){
dayList.push({key:diff[0],value:0});
}
console.log(dayList);
```